# Why "<Ctrl> + C" for copying does not work in Pidgin?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, pidgin

In pidgin, the shortcut of copying a text of chat history `<Ctrl> + C` does not work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: For Windows, OSX, Ubuntu, built from source, what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is working for you from other programs (e.g. not an issue with your keyboard), all I can  suggest is that it is either a custom component that pidgin uses for displaying the text which does not have control+c enabled/built in to it, or, the developers have decided to disable it.

Comment: On my system (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit) running Pidgin 2.7.10, Ctrl-C works fine.  So there must be something else going on here... like you said, perhaps this is symptomatic of a keyboard issue; or maybe a virus or spyware is infecting his system.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question is: "Because developers binded this shortcut for chat purposes".

To be more helpful: override short cut keybindings, adding to file `./.purple/gtkrc-2.0` like this:

```
binding "pidgin-copy" {
  bind "<ctrl>c" { "copy-clipboard" () }
}
class "*pidgin_conv_imhtml" binding "pidgin-copy"
```